# Kanban in Jira - Limit number of tasks in column

Tags: jira

I'm trying to limit the number of tasks displayed in one of our columns (the one which holds the "solved" tasks), without success.

I have changed the "MAX" column settings, but, it looks like it affect nothing. Still, all the tasks displayed in the column.

The main intention if this is to remove the clutter of old tasks that still displayed in "solved" column.

As you see in the example below, **Passed QA** column displays 610 tasks even thou max set to 50.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We faced the same problem with a 'Closed' column (about 100 tickets per week) but didn't want to hide the tickets as it is important for us to see at least the tickets closed the last few days.

We achieved this by adding  (resolution is empty or resolutiondate >= -2d) to the board filter. Maybe you can reduce the clutter of your column with that kind of filter.

Answer (score 1):

In JIRA Agile the column limits don't actually stop the columns from filling up because each column (in general) represents a workflow state (like In Progress or Done). The limits just alert you when there are too many issues in a certain state. This is important in Kanban, which emphasises limiting work in progress (the [Atlassian intro to Kanban](https://www.atlassian.com/agile/kanban) explains this in more detail).

It sounds like what you actually need is an additional status to be added to your workflow. For example, if you find the 'Passed QA' column is filling up with work that's actually been deployed, or moved to UAT then you could add a workflow step for that so that issues go from (e.g) Open > In Progress > Internal Testing > Passed QA > *Deployed to UAT* > *Deployed to production*. You probably have Resolved and Closed as statuses already so you could possibly use those (if they aren't already used to mean something different) or place another status in between.

Another way to handle this (as Prashant alluded to) would be to add a label or component to the issues that you want to hide (like 'ready to deploy' or similar) and then adding a [quick filter](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Configuring+Quick+Filters). A JQL query like 'labels not in ('ready to deploy') would remove those issues that didn't have that label.

But I'd concentrate on the workflow I think. It sounds like you may have identified a process problem, not a software usage problem.

Comment: Thank for answering Will. 
If I follow your suggestion with adding additional step in the flow, I will still get a column that with time will get full with tasks and all my screen will get "cluttered" with one huge column in the end... right?

Comment: You probably will, yes. But you can avoid this by having a status that isn't mapped to a column. I usually don't map 'Closed' to a column so once I've closed them they are no longer visible on the board. They'll still be findable in JIRA if you need them later. Go to Board > Configure > Columns to change the mappings.

Answer (score 1):

If you select "Release" that will clear the board. So you can select "Release" say every month and name it for eg. "Feb 2015" etc and batch what's been done monthly. Or you can select "release" everytime a release is done, or some other significant event.